# Laravel eloquent relationship is not working with foreach in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have Users Eloquent model like

```
class Users extends Model {

    public function branch() {
       return $this->hasOne(Branch::class, 'id', 'branch_id');
    }

    public function employee() {
       return $this->hasOne(Employee::class, 'id', 'employee_id');
    }
}
```

When I ran in a controller it works like a charm:

```
foreach(Users::all() as $user)
    dump($user->employee->first_name)
endforeach
```

But, the same code I want to run in Blade.php

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->employee->first_name}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Above code gives me **Trying to get property of non-object** Error.

Can anyone please help me?

I even tried

```
$users = Users::with('employee')->with('branch')->get();
```

Still no luck.

** Update 1 **

Here's the screenshot of collection 
[image: Collection]

Comment: can you print_r($users ) and add result .i guess posts are not there for some user

Comment: what are you sending back in response? show us that controller.

Comment: I haven't done Laravel in a long time, but I think the methods need to be called getEmployee and getBranch

Comment: try to dump `$users` and see the property your are looking for is exist or not

Comment: @iCoders I tried print_r and all the users have data. I checked it out. I am getting data like $user = Users::with('employee')->with('branch')->get() and I got employee and branch data in relation key. I'll post an image later.

Comment: are you sure your model name is `Users` because if not then you have to specify `protected $table = 'users'`

Comment: Yes, I customized it and add protected $table field. but still, I will double check it. thanks for your time.

Comment: As you can see this "Trying to get property of non-object" error inform that your users table branch_id | employee_id culumn data not match to the relation table.

That means - some times branch_id | employee_id having null value.

Answer (score 1):

I guess some users have no data in employee table so its throwing .check whether 
`$user->employee->first_name` isset

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
        <td>{{(isset($user->employee->first_name)?$user->employee->first_name:''}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

this issue might be that you are overriding `$users` in blade if it is working fine in `controller` so have a look in `AppServiceProvider.php` file if you used boot method.

For Example :

in **AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{

    View::composer('*', function($view){
        $view->with('users', ...);
    });

}
```

**OR**

try to dump `$users` in your blade file like

```
{{ dump($users) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across same type of issue but something different from the op.

If anyone comes across this question, when you are running foreach on a relationship then try adding *->get()*
example:

```
@foreach($user->transactions()->get() as $transaction)
```

Answer (score -2):

You should try this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
         @foreach($user->employee as $employee)
           <td>{{$employee->first_name}}</td>
         @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: how can this work because he is using `hasOne()` relationship

Comment: Exactly. @AjayDeepakKumar Strange behavior in controller and blade template file. Same code behaves differently.